# Android, Is it possible to write on the screen during play of movie?

Tags: android, splash-screen, movieclip

I want to design splash screen. 
In splash screen I want to show 5 seconds length movie (That i have downloaded from You-tube!) 
During the play of movie (for example from seconds 2 to 4) I want to show some texts (such as name of application) or putting image on the screen on top of movie (while movie is playing).

is it possible?

I know I can do this in movie instead of mixing with code, but i have no experience in making and editing movies and adding effects to them :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple. You don't have to do thinkgs like editing movie. Just add you videoview in an RelativeLayout and add your texts and images in that RelativeLayout at run time.

Comment: Ohhh, is it relay as simple as you told? Thats grate if it works :)